# How to wrap cell text in tables via docx library or xml?

Tags: python, xml, docx, python-docx

I have been using python docx library and oxml to automate some changes to my tables in my word document. Unfortunately, no matter what I do, I cannot wrap the text in the table cells.

I managed to successfully manipulate 'autofit' and 'fit-text' properties of my table, but non of them contribute to the wrapping of the text in the cells. I can see that there is a "w:noWrap" in the xml version of my word document and no matter what I do I cannot manipulate and remove it. I believe it is responsible for the word wrapping in my table.

for example in this case I am adding a table. I can fit text in cell and set autofit to 'true' but cannot for life of me wrap the text:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.oxml import OxmlElement
from docx.oxml.ns import qn

doc = Document()
table = doc.add_table(5,5)
table.autofit = True # Does Autofit but not wrapping

tc = table.cell(0,0)._tc     # As a test, fit text to cell 0,0
tcPr = tc.get_or_add_tcPr()

tcFitText = OxmlElement('w:tcFitText')
tcFitText.set(qn('w:val'),"true")
tcPr.append(tcFitText)      #Does fitting but no wrapping

doc.save('demo.docx')
```

I would appreciate any help or hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<w:noWrap>` element appears to be a child of `<w:tcPr>`, the element that controls table cell properties.

You should be able to access it from the table cell element using XPath:

```
tc = table.cell(0, 0)._tc
noWraps = tc.xpath(".//w:noWrap")
```

The `noWraps` variable here will then be a list containing zero or more `<w:noWrap>` elements, in your case probably one.

Deleting it is probably the simplest approach, which you can accomplish like this:

```
if noWraps:  # ---skip following code if list is empty---
    noWrap = noWraps[0]
    noWrap.getparent().remove(noWrap)
```

You can also take the approach of setting the value of the `w:val` attribute of the `w:noWrap` element, but then you have to get into specifying the Clark name of the attribute namespace, which adds some extra fuss and doesn't really produce a different outcome unless for some reason you want to keep that element around.

Comment: @ scanny Thank you so much and big fan of your work. The code works, but unfortunately not the way I thought it would. I am still having a situation in which the words break and split in the cells of my table and I was hoping the warping would address that. Autofit unfortunately does not. However, when I go in Microsoft Word, go to my table properties, the Cell tab, click the Options button and tick the Wrap text box, the problem is fixed. Is there Any way to achieve the same thing through code?

Comment: Best bet is to examine the XML produced by Word that produces the effect you want and then recreate it. You can get a start on inspection with `print(cell._tc.xml)`.